# How to remove default white screen in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have created a custom SplashScreen in my react native application and that's working fine.
But before that screen was called a white screen just came I want to remove that white screen.

Here is my SplashScreen component.

```
function SplashScreen(props) {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      hideSplashScreen();
    }, 5000);
  }, []);
  function hideSplashScreen() {
    setIsVisible(false);
  }

  return isVisible ? (
    <ImageBackground
      source={backgroundImage}
      style={{
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}>
      <Image
        source={triangleLogo}
        resizeMode={'cover'}
        style={{
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        }}
      />
    </ImageBackground>
  ) : (
    <LoginScreen />
  );
}

export default SplashScreen;
```

Comment: check how to add or splash screen from react native.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari
I do not want a SplashScreen I just want to load my SplashScreen component without that white screen.

Comment: I would suggest not to explicitly create a splash screen because js code may take more or less time than 5000s. The white screen you are seeing is the actual splash screen of the app.

Comment: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/splash-screens/

Comment: @SadiaChaudhary I want to remove that actual splash screen is there any way to remove that?

Comment: I don't think you can remove the splash screen altogether because it's required for app loading. The app needs to get ready to work so the splash screen is shown because of it.

Comment: @SadiaChaudhary I didn't see any screen when I build natively on android

Comment: That's because JS script  needs to be loaded and linked with native code in some sense.

Answer (score 1):

When the app launches, the app JavaScript bundle is loaded and parsed before executing and rendering the initial app screen.

For high-end devices like the latest iPhone Models, this delay happens instantly and is unnoticeable.

Differently, on Android low-end devices, this should take a few seconds and make your app seems slow to launch.

The rule of thumb to fix this issue is to add Splash Screen which runs on the native thread and doesn't require waiting for the JavaScript bundle to be loaded and parsed.

You can use one of the following packages:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bootsplash